# MATLAB arrayfun alternative in Python

Tags: python, matlab, vectorization

In MATLAB, I execute something like this:

```
z = diag(c)*D*x;
idxN = z<0; idxP = z>=0; % logical indexing
y1 = sum(-z(idxN))+sum(arrayfun(@(x) log(exp(x)+1),z(idxN)));
```

I'm trying to formulate a Python one:

```
z = np.diagflat(c).dot(D).dot(x)
idxN = z<0, idxP = z>=0
y1 = np.sum(-z[idxN])+np.sum(math.log(np.exp(x)+1),z[idxN]);
```

The above snippet doesn't work as I'm guessing I've to vectorize somewhere?

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: `arrayfun` isn't vectorization, it's shorthand for a loop. Just use a loop, or rewrite your code to use vectorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayfun` is a one-line wrapper for a loop in MATLAB. In Python, you can do it like this:

```
y1 = np.sum(-z[idxN]) + np.sum([math.log(np.exp(x)+1) for x in z[idxN]])
```